# .htaccess, combine two

Tags: .htaccess

How can i combine this rewrite-block:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^81\.216\.147\.82 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.168\.1\.9 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.nu
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.nu/$1 [R=301,L]
```

With this one?

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(blogg|tjanster|om-oss|kontakt|P[0-9]{2,8}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

First one just rewrites from ip to domain. Second one do that index.php will be called automaticly, like domain.nu/blogg will go through index.php

Comment: Just put one after the other in a .htaccess file? Or if you literally mean combine the two rules, curious why you would want to do that?

Comment: That will cause an infinite redirect loop :/

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing the first rewrite by:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(81\.216\.147\.82|192\.168\.1\.9|domain\.nu)
RewriteCond $1 ^(blogg|tjanster|om-oss|kontakt|P[0-9]{2,8}) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.nu/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(81\.216\.147\.82|192\.168\.1\.9|domain\.nu)
RewriteCond $1 ^index.php/(blogg|tjanster|om-oss|kontakt|P[0-9]{2,8}) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.nu/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first handle the case where the index.php is implicit and in the second its explicit.  The two cond sets are mutually exclusive so the ladder logic works.  (The condition is a regexp so its simpler to use the regexp syntax rather than [OR].)

Comment: That wont work :/, when i navigate to domain.nu/blogg it doesnt call index.php, because the server return 404 not found :(

Comment: OK, I've just ran these on my test VM (tweaked) for my IP etc. and they work for me.  I checked the rewrites on the rewrite.log and they worked as I expected.  Have you access to the rewrite.log

Comment: And can you enable rewrite logging temporarily?  Also have you checked the access.log / vhost.log on the www.domain.nu server to see what rewrites actually morphed into?